# 6 pin SMD identify on Gigabyte x570

Tags: identification, surface-mount

i have a x570 gigabyte motherboard that had a 6 pin smd chip missing in the back top right corner, the Ic next to the missing one is code AG0E with a 14 at 90 dregrees, ive been trying to identify it online with no luck,

[image]

have to say the motherboard wont turn on

Comment: The image isn't very clear, but it looks like traces were peeled up and damaged. Also, it would be helpful to know what the through-hole-soldered structure in the upper left is (i.e. is it a connector, and if so what kind?) as well as the chip label for HU2BU1 (lower right).

Comment: I'm guessing that the connector is a dual USB 3.0 connector. And the missing part is then likely ESD protection. Maybe something like this: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpd4e1u06.pdf?ts=1638994652092&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: I also think that is a quad USB connector and missing part was ESD protection.

Comment: the motherboard should be able to turn on with that missing part? some context: its a new motherboard, from a friend, that he got damaged with mounting.

Comment: Take a closer look at those 2-pin parts also missing form the board to the right of the 6-pin to make sure that there isn't anything bridging the pads together.

Comment: i did, it think its a cap and resistor

Comment: USB differential pairs are routed in the same way to the missing chip and the surviving one. They're probably identical ESD protection chips.

Comment: so the mobo should be able to turn on, just without that pair of usb working i am right?

Comment: @Androsk No, it's possible the mobo will turn on, and that USB will *appear* to work, but it will be missing a protective piece of circuitry and will be very easily at risk of damage. The missing chip is designed to absorb spikes of electrostatic discharge that could cause damage to other chips. When that chip is missing, if the lines between the port and other chips were unbroken, then the connection is still present but without protection.

Comment: @nanofarad, i mean, that the board does not turn on at all :(